# HTACCESS mobile redirect except specific url

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

How can I redirect mobile users to a mobile site but with some url exemption.

ie. 
example.com/main to example.com/mobile/main
but example.com/welcome should not redirect

here what I have

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,QSA,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,QSA,NC,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|googlebot-mobile|iemobile|ipad|iphone|ipod|opera mobile|palmos|webos" [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://example.com/mobile/ [L,R=302]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding a RewriteCond that excepts the URL you don't want rewritten. Something like this should work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,QSA,NC,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|googlebot-mobile|iemobile|ipad|iphone|ipod|opera mobile|palmos|webos" [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/welcome
RewriteRule ^$ http://example.com/mobile/ [L,R=302]
```

Comment: No problem. You might also want to consider moving this to the Apache server conf if you have the option, and disabling .htaccess, as the server will traverse the file tree looking for .htaccess files on each request otherwise.